# Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class) - Tried typical solutions already

Tags: java

I've seen many solutions posted to this issue and have not been able to spot the issue with my problem. I have had this problem before and HAVE fixed it, however, it recently just came back and I cannot think of anything that could have caused the reverse of the situation.

JDK and JRE versions are the same.

```
 $ java -version
 java version "1.7.0_21"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b12)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

 $ javac -version
 javac 1.7.0_21
```

JDK Versions folder.

```
 $ ls -al
 total 64
 drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 17 May 23:27 .
 drwxr-xr-x  11 root  wheel  374 15 May 21:48 ..
 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 15 May 19:00 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 15 May 19:00 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 15 May 19:00 1.5 -> CurrentJDK
 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 15 May 19:00 1.5.0 -> CurrentJDK
 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 15 May 19:00 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   10 15 May 19:00 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
 drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel  272 15 May 21:48 A
 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    1 15 May 19:00 Current -> A
 lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   64 17 May 23:27 CurrentJDK -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

The code in Eclipse is compiled with the same JDK version.
[image: JDK version in Eclipse build path]

Let me know what else I could be missing.

Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. CurrentJDK should have pointed to a depth of Contents folder only and not Home.